# F# Finding a Set in a Map

Tags: f#

So I have a database containing cars with an associated number and description. That database looks like this:

```
type Database = Map<CarNo, CarDesc>
type CarNo = int
type CarDesc = Name * Price
type Name = string
type Price = int
```

If I want to get the sum of the price of all the cars, based on the numbers, how would I make that function? I'm a little stuck on how to begin.

Any hints appreciated!

Comment: Use high order functions from the Map module to first filter by car # and then iterate in your Map

Comment: You should be more precise, "sum of all cars" ? how car can be summed (by price ?, by length of their name ?) ; "based on the numbers" ? which number (CarNo ?, Price ?), on which criteria ? All that said `Map.fold` will probably be your friend here

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, it's of course the price sum. I've edited the OP.

Comment: @Left4Cookies there are still a lot of info missing ; and also I don't get the point with the title, there is no mention of a **set** anywhere

Comment: As given here, the code doesn't compile. Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: When you retrieve the cars from the database what collection are they stored in? Is that a list, a sequence?

Comment: I assume your Name and price as string and float but I could be wrong about this .. Update !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would imagine that a function like this one would sum the prices of all the cars in your map. But contra the question title, there's no sets involved here.

```
let sumPrices (db:Database) = 
    db |> Map.fold (fun acc _ (_, price) -> acc + float price) 0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
db |> Seq.sumBy (fun (KeyValue (_, (_, price))) -> price)
```